# Best way to notify to phone from Python / JS script?

Tags: javascript, python, api, push-notification, sms

I am currently writing a script to notify me on my phone when a certain product goes on sale (no, I am not a scalper; I am buying a laptop for personal use, and they only currently go on sale for 60-15 minutes at a time in my country). However, I got a bit stuck when deciding on what API/service to use for notifying. Should I call / SMS? None of the APIs I saw were free for that. Any kind of notification service, should be a push notification or phone call, would work as long as they're free, and can preferably be used with JS/Python. Does anybody know a service that would work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: JS + Web Notifications, all free: https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging

Comment: @Nisala would that notify on a phone?

Comment: It should be able to send you a notification on any device with a web browser -- phones and computers included.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pushbullet
   https://www.pushbullet.com/
2. Telegram bot
   But user need to subscribe or join the bot channel, then develope a function to grab chat ID for distributing your messages.